# Error tfs246017 when connecting to TFS

Tags: tfs

I changed the IP address of the sql server TFS is connecting to but don't see any simple way to update the tfs config.

How to I change the ip address tfs is using to connect to sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the registerdb and remapdb commands to do this. You are effectively following the instructions for moving your DB server to new hardware.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance

You will have to do steps #10 onwards, but hopefully you stopped the TFS services first to prevent data loss...